# Linked to another Stackexchange site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On [this](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/view-close-votes) site (privileges, from main site) the link on this string is redirected to Meta Stack Overflow site:

> Other closed questions may be reopened through a similar voting process. They can also eventually be merged with another question or even [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a "parent" site for the Stack Exchange network, so many issues are covered on their meta and linked across the network.